# How do I fix my Error 404 without getting the same exact page everywhere? Dreamhost

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, internal-server-error

I've been getting a

> **Not Found**

> The requested URL was not found on this server.

> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

So I have found a fix for it which is

```
#RewriteEngine on

#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
#</IfModule>
```

However whem I used this fix it made every single page including the subpages display the index.html. Of course this is a problem for me again because i need it to display the intended pages, not the index.html everywhere

Comment: Where is your htaccess file present and where is your index.html file present? Kindly do let us know example/samples path here.

Comment: Both the htaccess and the index.html are at /home/[username]/[Website domain]/public

Comment: What exactly are you trying to fix? Are you suggesting these files being requested do exist? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: There is no way to answer this without knowing more about your site.  Your rule looks like you are implementing a front controller.  When you do so, `index.html` becomes responsible for managing its own status, but you would usually use PHP or another language that has the capability for doing so.   Or if you want to just enumerate a few URL paths for a SPA framework, that is a different fix.